# Handwritten digit recognition pre-processing (Rotation)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, mnist

[image: source: http://wbieniec.kis.p.lodz.pl/research/files/070618cores.pdf]

source: http://wbieniec.kis.p.lodz.pl/research/files/070618cores.pdf

I am currently performing some pre-processing to the MNIST data-set.  Some of the digits are quite rotated and I would like to get them upright before training my NN.  The logic above is what I would like to follow, however I do not think I have a good understanding of what it is trying to portray.  I would appreciate if someone, maybe someone who has performed something similar or has a good understanding of image processing, could validate the above logic.  Thanks

Comment: What exactly is unclear?You got your character and scale this one (some kind of normalization) possibly using a previously defined bounding-box. This is shown in the left picture (where i assume the left two pics are both inputs; the 3rd is a possible output). Now you rotate the whole box including the character with different angles and calculate new bounding-boxes (always consisting of vertical and  horizontal lines!) on the rotated character and calculate the width. Take the one which resulted in the smallest box width-wise. Compare the x-axis width of the two rotated ones on left and right

Comment: Is there a reason we have to decrease the height of the first input though?  It says 'have its height (at least slightly) larger than its width.  What was wrong with the initial tall '1'? Why did it need to be scaled down?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but i'm pretty sure, that this is a normalization-step which has the purpose of achieving coherent rotation-removals. Imagine two characters, which differ in their ratio (non-proportional font; or just different font sizes). The process above could result in different rotation-removals = post-rotations even if these two characters have the same a-priori rotation. I can imagine, this normalization step helps here. (Disclaimer: i have really no experience with character recognition)